# How to extract all audio start and end time from a video file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I need to know from a video file, how do I extract all audio timestamp meaning start time and end time of each dialog. Having tried with multiple ffmpeg or ffprobe commands but not getting the desire result.

My desire result would be like,

{'text': "Hello Robert! How are you", 'start': 0.15, 'end': 1.00}
{'text': "Hey, I'm fine. What's about you?", 'start': 1.35, 'end': 2.05}
.
.

Comment: Not possible. `ffmpeg` has no dialog parsing functionality.

Comment: Any other technique or way how do I get this?

Comment: Perhaps [autoEdit](https://www.autoedit.io/).